# Why we put a reg-exp in a list in python, like this [ ".*py$" ]?

Tags: python-2.7, optparse

I'm going through the following code, and I'm confusion about `options.plugins = [ ".*py$" ]`, Why we put a reg-exp in a list in python, like this [ ".*py$" ] ?

```
def main():
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-d", "--dist-logging", dest="dist_logging", help="use distributed logging", action="store_true", default=False)
    parser.add_option("-p", "--plugins", action="append", dest="plugins", help="a reg-exp of the plugins to load", metavar=".*py$")
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

initialize_logging(options.dist_logging)

if not options.plugins or len(options.plugins) == 0:
    options.plugins = [ ".*py$" ]
```

Comment: It's a list with a string inside of it.

Comment: List with one element, a string, which happens to be regular expression.

Comment: Thanks for your help,but could you explain this more detailed ? or could you share some link or article to introduce this more detailed, I tried to find some help from https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html, but seems there is not detailed info about this.

Comment: @phoenix, I revised my answer to explain a bit more what's happening. Take a look at it and see if it helps you understand, and feel free to vote or accept it if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the `[]` syntax [denotes a list](http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm), similar to array syntax in many other languages. In this case, what you're seeing is just a list that contains the string `".*py$"`.

If you look at the fourth line of your code, a `-p` or `--plugins` option is being created which will, per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#the-store-action):

> take the next argument (or the remainder of the current argument), ensure that it is of the correct type, and store it to your chosen destination.

In this case, the destination specified is, as you'll see, "plugins" - hence `options.plugins`. Further down, what's happening is that the code is checking if the `options.plugins` either doesn't exist or is empty. If so, it's setting it to a list containing one "option" string, which appears to be a regular expression.

The documentation I've found on optparse doesn't give much information on what it expects you to provide to `options.plugins`. However, generally speaking, the answer to this sort of question of "why do I assign X to Y" when working with an external library is simply that that's the input you're expected to provide when working with that particular library. Without any other context for this code it's hard to say much more than that about it.

Comment: Hi, sphanley, thanks for your kindly help and detailed explain, sorry for my bad question description which makes you misunderstand what Im confusing, now, I know '[ ".*py$" ]' is list with an member in it, and the member is an reg-exp, but I have never see that put a reg-exp in a list, and in this code, we put the reg-exp in a list, I want to know why the coder write in this way? the coder make a reg-exp as a list member here to resolve what problem? what is the purpose ?  @sphanley

Comment: Unfortunately I the documentation doesn't seem to describe the usage of `options.plugins`, and barring asking the person who wrote this code all I can do is speculate. I'd assume, though, that `options.plugins` expects a list of strings, perhaps each specifying a plugin to be used? Without more context for the code I can't really say much more for certain, perhaps someone more familiar with the Python OptionParser will drop by and know more.

Comment: maybe I should mail the coder, anyway, thanks for your help and instruction